# Is there any way to kill the running the deadlock thread "http:8080-42" which blocked all other thread

Tags: java, tomcat

We have an application which leaks a bit of memory, a bit being an understatement.

I am using jstack to try and find what is causing the problem.

I see the thread count grow quite a bit on threads starting with the name: http-8080- 42

example:

**"http-8080-13" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aacb4ae6000 nid=0x5ddf waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000043e65000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.reg_dashboard.DataModel.findRegsRow(DataModel.java:280)
    - waiting to lock <0x00002aaab0c996b0> (a java.lang.Class for com.reg_dashboard.DataModel)**

My first guess is that each of those threads is a request hit from the client and its waiting for some kind of synchronous block. 
My my problem is that those threads have been running for long periods of time (Thus far 10mins).

My question is this:

Is there any way to kill this thread which is causing my application to hang??? there is a some request which is loading the catche and got stuck and other process are waiting for object to get unlocked !

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to kill this thread which is causing my application
>   to hang???

Quite unlikely. The underlying JVM implementation should know how to react when an external process kills one of it's threads. You'll likely put the VM in an inconsistent state.

You already know where the dead lock is. Newer VMs pretty much tell you which threads are deadlocked with each other. Solve the problem at it's source instead of trying to kill the thread. Who is to say that the threads will not deadlock 10 seconds after you kill the locked threads (assuming that even works).

I'd recommend a tool like [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/features.html) if you'd like to take a deeper look at the locking mechanism in your application. You can solve the problem faster. I'm alluding to the `Monitor profiling` section.